# return same result at multiple time in code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

[i want to show specific award data for specific employee but it reutene same result at multipale time 
model function is here 
   public function get_all_awards($id = NULL) {

```
    $this->db->select('tbl_employee_award.*', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('tbl_employee.*', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('tbl_designations.*', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('tbl_department.department_name', FALSE);
    $this->db->from('tbl_employee_award');
    $this->db->join('tbl_employee', 'tbl_employee_award.employee_id  = tbl_employee.employee_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('tbl_designations', 'tbl_designations.designations_id  = tbl_employee.designations_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('tbl_department', 'tbl_department.department_id  = tbl_designations.department_id', 'left');
    $this->db->order_by("award_date", "desc");
    if (!empty($id)) {
        // var_dump($id);
        //die();
        $this->db->where('tbl_employee_award.employee_id',$id);
        $query_result = $this->db->get();

        $result = $query_result->row();

    } else {
        $query_result = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query_result->result();
    }
   // var_dump( $result->employee_id);
   // die();
    return $result;

}][1]
```

Comment: Make ```employee``` as your base table. Also don't select all data from tables, just select specific data you want.

Comment: how make employee table is base table . can  you code please sir

Comment: ```$this->db->from('tbl_employee_award');``` change this to ```$this->db->from('employee');```. and then join ```tbl_employee_award``` table to it and other tables too.

Comment: when i make employee table as base then nothing showing

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your base table as Employee table. Because you want data according to Employees not Awards.

```
public function get_all_awards($id = NULL)
{
    $this->db->select("E.id, E.employee_name, A.award_names, DES.designation,  D.department_name");
    $this->db->from('tbl_employee as E');
    $this->db->join('tbl_employee_award as A', 'A.employee_id = E.employee_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('tbl_designations as DES', 'DES.designations_id  = E.designations_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('tbl_department as D', 'D.department_id  = E.department_id', 'left');
    $this->db->order_by("A.award_date", "desc");    
    if($id !== NULL)
    {
        $this->db->where('E.employee_id', $id);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result = $query->result();
    print_r($result);
    die;
}
```

In above query, if you have single award for an employee then you will get single row in result. If an employee won multiple awards then it will return multiple rows for same employee but for different awards. If any employee won an award twice then also you get record twice.

Comment: thanks but is not work for me because   $query = $this->db->get(); (false)

Comment: ```$query = $this->db->get();``` whats wrong with this?

Comment: $query = $this->db->get();    
        var_dump($query);
        die();                                                  output bool(false)

Comment: ```return $query->result();``` this line will return the result... not this ```$query = $this->db->get();```

Comment: if($id !== NULL) var_dump($id ); die(); output 16 (that is employee id) but get fun. is not working

Comment: if you have records of that id in database, then you definitely get result.